# How azure sql geo replication handles transaction?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Say my azure database on azure is Geo replicated. On the primary server, I do this in a transaction:

```
DROP SYNONYM MyProduct;
Create SYNONYM MyProduct for NewDb;
```

On the secondary server, how this will be handled?

Say I have simple query:

```
select xxxx from MyProduct
```

Will I see random error such as

```
Invalid object name 'myDB.dbo.MyProduct'
```

(as if transaction is not respected, a query could run after the synonym is dropped but before the new Synonym is created)?

Will Azure SQL managed instance has the same behaviour as azure SQL db?

Answer (score 0):

I created synonym of table in another server using below code:

```
CREATE SYNONYM MyStudent  
FOR db.dbo.student;
```

I run below code in secondary server

```
Drop SYNONYM MyStudent 
CREATE SYNONYM MyStudent FOR db.dbo.student;
```

Output:

[image]

I tried to retrieve the data from synonym using below code:

```
select * from MyStudent
```

.I got below error:

[image]

> as if transaction is not respected, a query could run after the synonym is dropped but before the new Synonym is created?

Azure SQL Database provides asynchronous replication of transactions to any region.  The data in the secondary region is constant after the replication process. the transactions which are in the primary region those will appear in the secondary region, but it may take time to appear, and can't ensure that the transactions arrive in secondary reason will be same order of transactions which are in primary region. If transactions arrive in the secondary region are not in order, then the data in secondary region is not constant up to service catch's up.

> Will Azure SQL managed instance has the same behavior as azure SQL db?

Yes, Azure SQL managed instance has same behavior as Azure SQL database. But Active geo-replication is not supported by managed instance, instead of that failover groups are there in managed instance.
for more information you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/auto-failover-group-sql-mi?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#failover-group-status).